# What are units of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think $\langle -1,1\rangle, \langle-1,-1\rangle, \langle1,-1\rangle$ are the only units
since $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is unity and units are non-unity element?

Is it right?

Comment: I think often the identity is called a unit as well, but aside from that this looks right.

Comment: In general $U(R\times S)=U(R)\times U(S)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the three listed are unites.

The [definition that I believe is most common](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29) is that the unites of a ring $R$ are all elements $r$ for which there is an $s$ such that $rs = 1$. So with this definition you should also include $\langle 1, 1\rangle$.  In this way teh set of units in a ring is closed under multiplication" the product of two units is again a unit. Also, if you take the units of a field $F$, then you get $F^{\times} = F \setminus \{0\}$.

But maybe (and I really don't think this is the case) your textbook or class uses another definition. In this case you just get the three that you have listed.

Comment: I would have to imagine such a definition would get annoying very quickly. "An element $r \in R$ is irreducible if $r$ is nonzero, not a unit, not 1, and ...", "Since $r$ is not a unit and not 1, $(r)$ is contained in some maximal ideal" etc.

Comment: @rghthndsd: I agree.